# CSS3 center triangle on hover HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my css triangle to the middle of each navigation item when I hover over it. At the moment the triangle is under the front letter of each item. How do i do this?

If i remove position: absolute, it removes my triangle shape. How can i fix this?

```css
.current {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 8px solid #405580;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
  <nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making your `<a>` relative and then making your `nav a :hover :after` `relative`. I've added `margin-top` to push the arrow down, its up to you now to figure out some way to do that, withoout hardcoding it. :)

```
a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
}

nav a:hover:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border: 8px solid #405580;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left:33%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/daveRanjan/pen/yXyWwR

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created your triangle as an `:after` pseudo-element, you can make it's position relative to `nav a`. Keep `position: absolute` on the triangle, just adjust it's `bottom` positioning to how you want it. Create a new style element for `nav a` and add to it `position: relative`. See below.

```css
.current {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

nav a {
   position: relative;
}

nav a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 8px solid #405580;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
  <nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Noticed this actually hasnt worked - this has now moved to the center of the navigation on top of the "Home" etc. I want it underneath the navigation bar in the center of the text.

Comment: Keep in mind, you asked for the triangle to be positioned at the middle 'of each' navigation item. Hence my response. So, you want your triangle to be below the navbar vertically, but in the middle horizontally?

Comment: sorry for the confusion but yes that's correct. It is currently under the navigation bar, however it is underneath the first letter of each navigation item. I want it to go horizontally so it appears in the middle of each navigation item. Does this make sense?  E. If I hover over "home" the triangle should be under this pointing inbetween the o and the m. It is currently pointing under the h

Comment: Did that make sense?